# HSA without a HDHP [USA]

Tags: united-states, taxes, hsa, hdhp

I had an HSA with an HDHP with a former employeer. I left that company and now have a traditional health insurance plan.

Should I continue to contribute to my old HSA account?
Are there any tax consequences of using the money in that account toward current medical expenses?
Should I add my new spouse to the plan?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should **not** continue contributing, as you're no longer qualified for it. You can keep it, and use the money in it toward the current medical expenses, without a problem. There are specific examples in [pub 969](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p969/index.html).

Comment: It is possible his new traditional plan meets the guidelines for being an hdhp, right?